# Map Local (like Charles Proxy) using Open Source

Tags: web-development, http-proxy

Is there a way to use Wireshark or some other freeware to get an outcome like one gets when using Charles' Map Local capability?

The way it works in Charles is that you can specify a set of files/folders which are replaced with files from your local disk, anytime your browser requests the specified file(s).

This is **super** handy for working on complex websites with barriers to getting your changes into source-control, or where you are not allowed to push files onto a staging server during development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for an open-source solution, then [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) might be a solution.

Privoxy can do [redirect actions](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#REDIRECT) and much more.
These examples were taken from the manual :

```
# Replace example.com's style sheet with another one
{ +redirect{http://localhost/example.com.css} }
example.com/stylesheet\.css$

# Redirect remote requests for this manual
# to the local version delivered by Privoxy
{+redirect{s@^http://www@http://config@}}
www.privoxy.org/user-manual/
```

Comment: I tried using Privoxy, but it seemed to have issues with https. There's also https://dutzi.github.io/tamper/ Tamper based on mitmproxy but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @BenCreasy: The Privoxy FAQ [says](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html#SSL): " Since secure HTTP connections are encrypted ... there is little that Privoxy can do but hand the raw gibberish data though from one end to the other unprocessed. The only exception to this is blocking by host patterns". Nevertheless, someone has managed it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ijbswa/support-requests/1667/) using ProxHTTPSProxy.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [tamper](https://dutzi.github.io/tamper/) which uses the popular Python library [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy).

It did not work for me, but the code is open source so you can probably get it working if you put in the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since asking this question, I have found out that you **can** [do this with Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821224/intercept-and-use-local-files-in-http-requests). This is not strictly an answer, I was asking for something Open Source, and AFAIK Fiddler is **not** open source.

I'm still holding out for some other easy way to do this, but for now this seems to be the answser. No.